# Calculate correlation between events and signals in time series

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, rare-events

I have a time series signal (continuous values) and some events occurring. An event for me is characterized by the fact that it only has a single timestamp assigned to it and not a timespan.

Is there any correlation measure to calculate the relationship between the signal and the event? The use case would be, that I want to find out which events are responsible for an increase of the continuous signal, for example.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can do a point process regression.

Answer (score 1):

This can be analyzed using Intervention Modeling.  It is a regression with a causal variable where you have zeroes before the event and then a 1 from the event and forward.  The t-value will tell you the magnitude of the impact.